# Test between key down and key up event

Tags: android, junit, key-events

Is there a possibility to run test between application's key down and key up event handlers? I develope 2D arcade game, gameThread inside gameView handles key press. I wrote JUnit Android Testing Project.
I have read about this.sendKeys(), but it seems, that this method sends key up, then down signals.

DETAILS:
I'll be using both - touch & non-touch interaction. But now I'm testing

non-touch. So I wrote:

`protected void setUp() throws Exception {

```
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    _activity = (GameTemplate) getActivity();
    <...>
```

}`

as test initialize.

I wrote test to ensure, that keyUp event processed well:

`public void testReturnState() {

```
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
    _instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
assertTrue(_logic.getSerp().state().equals(SerpentState.SERP_MOVES_FORWARD));

}`
```

It works ok, but I wrote another test:

`public void testKeysSimple() {

```
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
    assertTrue(_logic.getSerp().state().equals(SerpentState.SERP_MOVES_LEFT));

}`
```

It fails, I think it happens because of one of two reasons:

1) program hasn't handled keyDown event yet;

2) program has handled both keyDown and keyUp events

I'm new to testing, maybe all could be done much easier in another way. Please, help me.

I tried to add repeats in test:

```
public void testKeysUpDown() {  
    int t = TSet.skips;
    this.sendRepeatedKeys(TSet.keyRepeats,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
    while(t>0 && !_logic.getSerp().state().equals(SerpentState.SERP_MOVES_LEFT)) t--;
    assertTrue(t>0);
}
```

but it also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Instrumentation#sendKeySync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendKeySync%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) to have full control over the event sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using touch based interaction, then you can use MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. This is when user has touched the screen and dragging without lifting the finger up.

Code Snippet

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {

    switch (rawEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // First touch on the screen
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        // Multi-touch on the screen
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Lift from the screen
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        // Multi-Lift from the screen
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Drag on the screen
        break;
    }

}
```

Shash

Comment: I'm writing test for non-touch event now. I've brought details to my question. See above, this is my first question here, so sorry, if something wrong.

Comment: I have two projects: Game and GameTest, second tests first. Your code is a method, which cann't be ran on a test-side. Though, maybe I don't know some testing mechanisms. If so, tell me please.